# SQL Explicit Batch Execution

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2005

Lets say I have this batch:

```
// Insert two order lines for order #2002 (Order_Lines table)
// Update order #2002 Total Quantity (Orders table)

INSERT INTO Order_Lines (OrderID, Line, PartID, Quantity)
   VALUES (2002, 1, 1234, 10);
INSERT INTO Order_Lines (OrderID, Line, PartID, Quantity)
   VALUES (2002, 2, 5678, 5);
UPDATE Orders 
   SET TotalQty = (SELECT SUM(Quantity) FROM Order_Lines WHERE OrderID = 2002)
   WHERE OrderID = 2002;
```

When I run this, does the server wait for each statement in the batch to finish executing before it starts executing the next statement?

What I really want to know is if the Orders table will be updated correctly if I run this batch. (If the Inserts are executed first and the Update last, it should be updated correctly.)

By the way, I'm using a SQL 2005 and a 2008 server.

Comment: Statement execution is serial. Each statement will execute one after the other, potentially even if one fails. You should look at `SET XACT_ABORT ON` and its effects on queries executed in the same batch.

Comment: @ta.speot.is: Thank you for the tip on 'SET XACT_ABORT ON'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can expect the results of each statement to be available to subsequent statements.

Comment: Caveat: A statement has to succeed to have its side-effects available to subsequent statements.